# How DataFrame API apply Data Abstraction and Domain Specific Language (DSL) on structure and semi structured data in SparkSQL?

Tags: apache-spark, datasource, apache-spark-sql, dsl

Can anyone please elaborate the concept of the statement that DataFrame API is a Data Abstraction and Domain Specific Language (DSL) applicable on structure and semi structured data?

Comment: It's an abstraction over the core RDD API and can be accessed using simple SQL statements.

Comment: @philantrovert please answer below with a bit more explanation :)

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I don't think I can explain it more than that. I am not good with words :D

Comment: @philantrovert Don't think yourself that you are not good in words. :) You can do it.

Comment: @philantrovert just explain as much as you can . :) you can copy paste you comment as well.